# Trying to narrow down the cause of a Bluetooth headphone app-specific sound issue

Tags: audio, bluetooth, windows-11, sound-card, headphones

So before I go on in length let me just say that this problem has been fixed on a practical level. The reason I'm still attacking the problem is that the fixes make absolutely no sense to me and I'm more confused than ever.

In a sense that makes this a mostly academic exercise, but I *really* want to pinpoint what the exact problem is.

**Issue:** The specific games/apps Oblivion (GOG) and New Vegas (GOG) have audio issues (crackling, stuttering) exactly when using Bose QuietComfort 35 Bluetooth headphones. For me this issue is only present on the MSI laptop given below.

**System:** MSI Vector GP76 12UHSO. i9-12900H (2.90 GHz). RAM 64 GB. NVIDIA RTX 3080 Ti (16 GB). Windows 11.

**Solutions:** There are several ways to resolve the problem.

1. Turn output to speakers (Realtek Audio). Bad solution since the point is to use headphones, not speakers.
2. Turn output to MSI Sound Tune. This solution is bad for two reasons. First, the audio level is absurdly low for some reason. Second, I don't know why a noise cancelling device is a functioning audio output.
3. Open another app whose sound works, such as YouTube on any browser, another game, any audio/video file on MPC, etc. At this point I can leave the other app on play or pause. Either way, once I start the games Oblivion or New Vegas, the broken audio is fixed.

The third solution has to be a clue, but I'm unsure what to make of it. Other folk on the games' discussion forums seem to also have stumbled on this last solution, though many incorrectly list needing to additionally turn off audio enhancements and so on and so forth. It is sufficient to have a working audio source playing.

Anyways, thanks for reading and I'd appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is essentially a game bug.

An unsupported audio format, such as a signal with too high or too low of a sample rate or bit-depth, can cause issues if the application attempts to fulfill a request outside of its capabilities. Since audio from multiple applications is mixed together for output, the other applications running first are correctly initializing the output to the audio device, providing a pathway for Oblivion and New Vegas to output correctly. Try changing the default format in Windows audio settings:[image: screenshot of Windows System Sound Properties with format highlight]

It is unlikely that the games' audio is higher quality than 16-bit 48KHz, any higher setting is unlikely to improve the audio.